# When will eventfd_read() block?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

I wonder under what situation `eventfd_read()` will block?

I read the manpage but it doesn't mention anything.

I created the file descriptor through `eventfd(0,0)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`eventfd(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) man page for `read()` call:

> If the eventfd counter is zero at the time of the call to
>                    read(2), then the call either blocks until the counter
>                    becomes nonzero (at which time, the read(2) proceeds as
>                    described above) or fails with the error EAGAIN if the file
>                    descriptor has been made nonblocking.

And for `eventfd_read()` and `eventfd_write()` functions:

> The functions perform the read and write operations on an eventfd
>          file descriptor, returning 0 if the correct number of bytes was
>          transferred, or -1 otherwise.

So `eventfd_read()` is just wrapper for `read()` and blocks when `read()` blocks, i.e. when `eventfd` counter is zero and `O_NONBLOCK` is not set for a descriptor (using [`fcntl(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) or `EFD_NONBLOCK`).

You can verify this in [glibc sources](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/eventfd_read.c):

```
int
eventfd_read (int fd, eventfd_t *value)
{
  return __read (fd, value, sizeof (eventfd_t)) != sizeof (eventfd_t) ? -1 : 0;
}
```